# What is the portable way in CMake to determine the size of a file?

Tags: windows, scripting, posix, cmake, portable-applications

I need to determine the number of bytes in an arbitrary file via a CMake script, but in a portable manner.

This file may be large, so reading it in with the file(READ...) command and counting the string length isn't optimal.

If I only had to run on MacOS and/or Linux I'd just use `wc -c`, which gives me exactly what I want. But the script needs to be Windows compatible assuming only the Windows toolchain. (I'm not very knowledgeable with Windows development.)

I expected this to be a common operation, but am not finding anything similar in the CMake Modules source (likely searching for the wrong thing), and it doesn't appear to be supported by andy of the `cmake -E` commands.

So I'm looking for either some clever way of getting this info with a single command, or a recommendation on what command(s) I could use in Windows and wrap around a `if(WIN32)` conditional.

Comment: I am curious on why you would think this is a common operation.

Comment: In a tool designed for creating and inspecting files of various types, the size of a file is a fundamental property. @sakara's solution also includes a `TIMESTAMP` sub-command, another fundamental property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a CMake module called [FileInformation](https://github.com/sakra/FileInformation) which lets you obtain the size of a file in a portable way. It adds a new sub-command to CMake's built-in `file` command:

```
file (SIZE filename variable)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing this module. Really should be part of the official distro.

Comment: I'm curious to know if the `macro(file)` override and use of `_file()` is a common pattern that can be used with all CMake commands, or if it's only possible because the underlying implementation of `file(...)` provides this capability? I'm at a loss to find documentation on this. It's a very powerful mechanism.

Comment: It's a common pattern that was mentioned on the CMake mailing list. See [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-October/032725.html).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're going to like this, but I think compiling and running a small C program and using its output would be the easiest way to do this. After all, what you need to do is pretty custom, but easy to do in C.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

try_run(RUN_RESULT COMPILE_RESULT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filesize.c
    RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE FILE_SIZE
    ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bigfile)

if (NOT COMPILE_RESULT)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Filesize failed to compile")
endif()

if (RUN_RESULT EQUAL 0)
    message(STATUS "Filesize ${FILE_SIZE}")
else()
    message(WARNING "Filesize failed")
endif()
```

And in filesize.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (fp != NULL) {
                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
                printf("%d", ftell(fp));
                fclose(fp);
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

COMPILE_RESULT is TRUE or FALSE. And if the file isn't found try_run returns an error (in RUN_RESULT). Otherwise cmake runs the program, which seeks to the end of the file and prints the size in bytes. The result is captured in the FILE_SIZE variable.

The only problem with this is that it won't work for cross-compilation, as try_run doesn't run anything in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed approach, and the reminder that CMake is quite good at creating on the fly utilities. I accepted @sakra's answer because it integrates so nicely with the existing `file()` command and is wrapped up nicely in a module. This is an excellent and helpful answer as well.

Comment: True, plus sakra's solution would work for cross-compiled code since it doesn't rely on compiled code, instead using platform-specific scripting (though platform-specific scripting is a very slippery slope to go down!).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for short files you can do:

```
function(get_file_size var filename)
    file(READ "${filename}" content HEX)
    string(LENGTH "${content}" content_length)
    math(EXPR content_length "${content_length} / 2")
    set(${var} ${content_length} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

get_file_size(len "main.c")
message(STATUS "len(main.c)=${len}")
```

Comment: You need some extra quoting, e.g. `string(LENGTH "${content}" content_length)` in case the file contains semicolons. Yes CMake quoting is weird.